# Font "bottom-padding" is bigger than expected

Tags: html, css, fonts, less

I've recently bought `Proxima Nova` font for my project and I am having issue aligning it vertically. If I set all the margins, line-heights and padding exactly as with `Arial`, I don't get the same results and the font is misaligned. You can see the `Arial` is nicely centered and the `Proxima nova`'s bottom padding is bigger than the top padding.

I suppose it is a problem with the font - the question is - how can I overcome the issue? Do I have to redo the font? Can I set up some css property to fix this?

I've created a page to demonstrate the issue:

http://fonts.knyt.tl/

[image]
**Edit**:

My question is - is there a way to globally "configure the font" to have the correct paddings so that I don't have to rewrite the whole css code once I decide to change the font? Or do I have to edit the font files to achieve this?

Comment: I don't see any issues in FF Chrome? which browser are you using to generate above issue?

Comment: I can see it in both FF and Chrome, if you measure the pixels in the top and bottom, you will see what I mean.

Comment: Try it by removing the padding and then adding the line-height. font-size: 20px line-height: 40px;

Comment: Vikas: No effect, still the same problem.

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome on Linux (as long as you use `line-height: 1;`).

Comment: It's such a minor thing - most people here don't even notice it after you tell them what to look for.  You think any users would notice it without being told?  I don't think so.

Comment: Andi: that is just personal opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinks, its the problem with the `font`. The font you used, ie; 'proximanova' takes a little padding in its bottom. Either, u should adjust your padding as

```
padding: 10px 10px 8px 10px;
```

or change the 'font' file used.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well I don't want to have my css code full of paddings which are specific because of the font. I don't want to rewrite all the css once I decide to change the font.

Comment: In the end we replaced the font. Thanks to all.

Comment: Just spend an hour debugging this extra space. Was starting to doubt my career choice!

Answer (score 1):

It's looking fine here. Don't have any idea what's wrong with it, but make a check if some add-on or extension is creating problems in font appearance.

And of course, adjusting the font with `padding` attribute is not a good practice, so better avoid it.

Comment: Haven't yet tested on windows, but it happens on all Apple OSX.

Comment: Its in windows too, I've tested.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the font's line-height is accommodating the [descender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender). Try adding a y or lowercase j and see if it descends below the baseline.